# EF6 exception: DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm facing an exception when I run this query (using LinqPad for debugging):

```
int[] serviceCodes= new int[] { 1610, 1611, 1612 };
byte[] payModes = new byte[] { 1, 2 };
int[] months = new int[] { 10, 11, 12 };
int year = 2017;

using (var context = new FinanceConnection())
{
   var result = from a in
            (from a in context.BILL_INFO_DETAILS
             where
                 a.INPUT_STATUS == true &&
                 serviceCodes.Contains(a.SERVICE_INFO.SERVICE_CODE) &&
                 payModes.Contains(a.PAY_MODE_ID) &&
                 a.STAMP_DATE != null &&
                 months.Contains(a.STAMP_DATE.Value.Month) &&
                 a.STAMP_DATE.Value.Year == year &&
                 a.SERVICE_INFO.FEE > 1
             select new
             {
                 a.REQUESTED_QTY,
                 a.ITEM_TOTAL,
                 Dummy = "x"
             })
             group a by new { a.Dummy }
        into g
             select new ViewGuessAlMajlisOffline
             {
                 Transaction =
                     g.Sum(p => p.REQUESTED_QTY) == 0 ? (int?)null : (int)g.Sum(p => p.REQUESTED_QTY),
                 Income = g.Sum(p => p.ITEM_TOTAL) == 0
                     ? (decimal?)null
                     : (decimal)g.Sum(p => p.ITEM_TOTAL)
             }; 

    result.Dump();
}
```

I have searched the SO questions with the same titles but my contain lists are simple arrays so I don't know what is actually causing the exception.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

**Update**

I have tried removing the two `.Contains()` in where and the query works. Actually, commenting only the `payModes.Contains(a.PAY_MODE_ID)` makes the query work

**Update**

```
public partial class BILL_INFO_DETAIL : DA.Services.IBS.Data.EntityFramework.Helper.IBaseEntity
{
    public string BILL_NO { get; set; }
    public byte PAY_MODE_ID { get; set; }
    public int CASHIER_NO { get; set; }
    public int SERVICE_CODE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> REQUESTED_QTY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CURRENT_QTY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> FEE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ITEM_TOTAL { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> VAT_AMOUNT { get; set; }
    public string USER_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BUSINESS_USER_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> INPUT_STATUS { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> STAMP_DATE { get; set; }

    public virtual BUSINESS_USER BUSINESS_USER { get; set; }
    public virtual CASHIER CASHIER { get; set; }
    public virtual PAY_MODE PAY_MODE { get; set; }
    public virtual SERVICE_INFO SERVICE_INFO { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a model of BILL_INFO_DETAIL?

Comment: @Evk, I just updated the question with the model

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seem to be a bug (in both EF6.1.3 and 6.2) with `Contains` method translation when applied on `byte` array (probably because usually the byte arrays are used to represent binary data).

The workaround is to use `int` array:

```
var payModes = new int[] { 1, 2 };
```

or explicit enumerable (to avoid `byte[]` special processing):

```
var payModes = new byte[] { 1, 2 }.AsEnumerable();
```

Note that the conversion to enumerable should be outside the query expression tree, because `AsEnumerable()` call is not recognized by the EF query translator and will generate `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: `IEnumerable<byte> payModes = new byte[] { 1, 2 };` seems to be adequate.