# Failed to convert parameter value from a Byte[] to a Byte

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a below class

```
public partial class ClubMember
{
    public Guid ClubId { get; set; }
    public Guid MemberId { get; set; }
    public byte ClubRoleId { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

    public Club Club { get; set; }
    public ClubRole ClubRole { get; set; }
    public UserEntity Member { get; set; }
}
```

when querying as below

```
byte[] a = new byte[]{3,4 };
dbContext.ClubMember.Where(cm => a.Contains(cm.ClubRoleId))
```

This throws error like

> Failed to convert parameter value from a Byte[] to a Byte.

Comment: What is the exact data type of column `ClubRoleId` in database?

Comment: This sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123858/ef6-exception-dbexpressionbinding-requires-an-input-expression-with-a-collectio/49126782#49126782 in EF6. I guess the cause is similar (special treatment of `byte[]` and translation bug), so should be the solution.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'd say it's the same case and the bug was ported over to Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two overloads of `Contains` for arrays. One is `Contains(T arg)` and another is `Contains(T[] args)` and you are getting the wrong one.

You could try using `Any` method. For sample:

```
byte[] a = new byte[]{ 3, 4 };
var result = dbContext.ClubMember.Where(cm => a.Any(b => b == cm.ClubRoleId));
```

Using `Any`, the Entity Framework will perform a `IN` filter over the column you want. Something, you can add another queryable instance over the `Any` scope and it perform a subquery.

You also can use a `List` instead of array, for sample:

```
var a = new List<byte>() { 3, 4 };
var result = dbContext.ClubMember.Where(cm => a.Contains(cm.ClubRoleId));
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not the case. OP is definitely hitting `Contains(byte)`.

Comment: This is not the case, as IntelliSense shows me. Also, in any case, `List<T>` contains 3 `Contains` while `T[]` contains 2 (which are both LINQ-provided). The solution is to use `List<T>.Contains` which is not from LINQ

Comment: The second (updated) solution should solve the issue, but can you explain why?

Comment: @IvanStoev - It is due to special treatment of `byte[]` (perhaps similar to what you added to question comments). EF Core does not expand `byte[]` array parameter for In Expression. So when you use enumerable other than `byte[]` it starts working. I will look into finding reason for special treatment.